# How should I use imports for subfolders with go modules?

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm unsure about the imports when it comes to subfolders. My gopath is "/home/username/go" and my project is located in "/home/codeboxx/go/src/project".
.
Say my project tree looks like this :

```
- project
  - foldera
    - foldera.go
  - folderb
    - folderb.go
  - go.mod
  - go.sum
  - main.go
```

If in my main.go I import something like "github.com/gorilla/mux", but in my foldera.go I also need this import, how do I do it? Obviously I could just import "github.com/gorilla/mux" again in my foldera.go, but if my module name is like "potato", can't I just do something like "potato/github.com/gorilla/mux" in my foldera.go? I'm wondering because I want everything to be up-to-date with the same versions. Should i just init a go.mod in each subfolders for those? Local packages I don't have trouble doing something like "potato/somepackage" in foldera.go.

I'm probably misunderstanding something, but I've been looking on google and I don't understand it..

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will all use the same version regardless, just because it's in a different folder doesn't mean it will ignore the root go.mod

Comment: so the "github.com/gorilla/mux" of foldera.go will always be up to date with the one from the potato module even though I just import it as "github.com/gorilla/mux" and nothing relates to the "potato" module? Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: correct, except when you say "nothing relates to the potato module" - everything inside of the folder with `go.mod`, including subfolders, are part of that module (unless they have their own go.mod possibly)

Comment: Oh okay. I thought that because we weren't mentionning the module name like a local package it wasn't really related. I also thought that since I had it in my modules in my subfolder I wouldn't even need the import "github...". Oh well, thanks a lot!